# Replacing n values in raster using two different rasters in R

Tags: r, raster-calculator

I have 2 rasters:

1. raster 1 is a water mask where 1 means water and 0 surface;
2. raster 2, I want to exclude water using raster 1.

So, I want to make a script like that:

if water is 1, put nodata in the similar pixel in raster 2.

I'm trying, but I cannot do it in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, just use `mask(raster , mask_layer , maskvalue = 1)`. Reproducible example:

```r
library(raster)
library(RStoolbox)

ggRGB(lsat, stretch = 'lin')
```

[image]

```r
mndwi <- (lsat[[2]]-lsat[[5]])/(lsat[[2]]+lsat[[5]])

ggR(mndwi, geom_raster = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
water_mask <- mndwi > 0

ggR(water_mask, geom_raster = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
lsat_without_water <- mask(lsat, water_mask, maskvalue=1)

ggRGB(lsat_without_water, stretch = 'lin')
```

[image]